# TypeError: Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nodemon

[I'm getting this error while i try to fetch document from my mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2xni.png)
i'm using mongo for the first time, if anyone can help me out, it would be great

```
const express = require("express");
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
const { connectToDb, getDb } = require("./db");

const app = express();

//db connection
let db;
connectToDb((err) => {
  if (!err) {
    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("App listerning on Port :3000");
    });
    db = getDb();
  }
});

//route connections
app.get("/books", (req, res) => {
  let books = [];
  db.collection("books")
    .find()
    .sort({ author: 1 })
    .forEach((book) => books.push(book))
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json(books);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Couldn't fetch the documents" });
    });
});

app.get("/books/:id", (req, res) => {
  db.collection("books")
    .findOne({ _id: ObjectId("req.params.id") })
    .then((doc) => {
      res.status(200).json(doc);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "could not fetch the document" });
    });
});
```

want to know how to get rid of this error and what is causing this

Comment: Well `ObjectId("req.params.id")` is not using `new`… and did you really mean to pass a string?!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it worked for me, simply store new ObjectId() in a variable (id) and then access that variable inside of the  method as shown below

```
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");

app.get("/books/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = new ObjectId(req.params.id);

  if (ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    db.collection("books")
      .findOne({ _id: id })
      .then((doc) => {
        res.status(200).json(doc);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Could not fetch the documents" });
      });
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Not a valid doc id" });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
const { connectToDb, getDb } = require("./db");

const app = express();

//db connection
let db;
connectToDb((err) => {
  if (!err) {
    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("App listerning on Port :3000");
    });
    db = getDb();
  }
});

//route connections
app.get("/books", (req, res) => {
  let books = [];
  db.collection("books")
    .find()
    .sort({ author: 1 })
    .forEach((book) => books.push(book))
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json(books);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Couldn't fetch the documents" });
    });
});

app.get("/books/:id", (req, res) => {
  db.collection("books")
    .findOne({ _id: new ObjectId("req.params.id") })
    .then((doc) => {
      res.status(200).json(doc);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "could not fetch the document" });
    });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).